# Scrolling to a section of a Page from an external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to navigate to a particular section of a page, say www.oneurl.com/abc.html from an www.externalurl.com/xyz.html...

I tried with very basic functionality by using #tag as

**xyz.html**

```
<a href="http://www.oneurl.com/abc.html#deduct">Test</a>
```

**abc.html**

```
<section id="deduct">Test</section>
```

But when I click on the link, the page gets loaded but it doesn't scrolls or shows the section.

Comment: the anchor #deduct should work like this. (example: http://stackoverflow.com/#footer-sites)

Comment: i've try and it work good for me, is you're page abc.html height> size of screen ? It work only if u're section deduct is not visible on the screen without scrolling

Comment: maybe an internet lag? maybe the document is not loading fast enough?

Comment: The domains of source and target is different, is this the reason is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Hello OM The Eternity,

This is the code I have and it works for me without a problem, I am using Chrome.

first HTML file

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr#author-45677">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click that link it takes me to the page and it loads up looking at the div with the correct id. I have also created a jsFiddle

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jotxffL5/

Make sure you are targeting an ID that exists. This also works fine even if the sites are on different domains

Answer (score -1):

And if all else fails, try using the HTML4 way of handling named links:

```
<a name="deduct">Test</a>
```

Comment: That's HTML 3.2, not HTML 4, and if IDs don't work then there is no reason that should.